# Logging Analytics API

Tags: google-oauth

I wrote an application that downloads data from Analytics API.  I didn’t have problem with login I used the  OAuth 2.0 on my first computer, the problem is that now I’ve changed to my laptop, the authentication doesn’t work correctly.

The program use the next url for obtain the authentication:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:53636/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly

If I put this url in the old laptop the login works, but If I use the same url for login in the new laptop only obtain a access without connection.

I don’t understand why I get different results depends on the computer.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?  My guess is it has something to do with the port number in your redirect_uri

Comment: he problem is that while I obtain the full access data with the old laptop, the new laptop only obtains  data without conexion permissions. The url executed in both laptops is the same, and the account conexion is the same. Do I need a differents Client ID for differents laptops? Thanks in advance

Comment: You only need one client id.   What is a conexion permission?  Try and post your error message

Comment: Sorry, I can't attached a image becouse I don't have enought reputation for post it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't attach an image becouse I don't have enought reputation for post it. Exactly google says, ProjjectXXX wants to do the next: **have access without connection** (Proyecto XXX quiere hacer lo siguiente: **Tener acceso sin conexion**). The account has all privileges for access data.

Comment: This is not an Analytics API question, but an Authentication related question. Secondly, you have set the redirect URI to localhost, meaning a server running on your machine. The first question then would be, do you have a server running on your new machine that can accept connections on that port?

Comment: Done, it was a problem with the cookies of the navigator, I cleaned the cookies and history, and Ready.

Thanks for your interest. Pete and DalmTo